# Who should I focus fire (discord) with Zen?

Tags: overwatch

Which group of heroes should be my target, ordered from most to least important ?
I personally tend to discord Reinhardt (tanks) as soon as he drops his shield to fire strike, and if a flanker attacks me or goes behind us in general, I'd prioritise them, so they'd die quicker and I'd have an idea where they're hiding. In a big team fight I'd juggle between tanks and support. Am i doing it right or is there some room for improvement?

Comment: This feels an awful lot like "Who should I attack?"

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Left or right click is one thing, I'm asking who to place my 30%+ dmg to, so that my entire team can benefit the most out of it. I have a fairly good idea who to attack myself.

Comment: Then put the Orb on whoever you're attacking.

Comment: I would say you are already doing the correct Zen strategy.  Mark any available tank or infiltrator or whoever you are attacking as @DanmakuGrazer said.

Comment: @ИвоНедев The answer to this question is going to vary depending on different playstyles. I personally swap discord targets literally every single time I start attacking a new target. Others mark one "high priority" (in their minds) target and leave it on them so their team can clean up. There's benefits and drawbacks to both methods. Use whatever feels natural - in the end, as long as your Discord Orb is on *someone*, you and your team will be doing extra damage to *someone*.

Comment: @MageXy The amount of damage amplified by a target with Orb of Discord has been decreased from 50% to 30%

Comment: @ИвоНедев So it is. Hmm, not sure where I got the 20% from.

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/269668/how-can-i-be-an-effective-support-with-zenyatta/269671#269671

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In light firefights**

When there's only a few members of each team, it's best to target either those who do high damage, or the healer. These are high priority targets you want out the way as fast as possible.

**In big team fights where many people have their ult**

Ideally you want to target people who have gamechanging ults. For example, you want to slap it on mercy to get her out of the fight right away, before she res's her entire team. This can also work on Lucio if you suspect he also has his ult. It's also important to put it on people who are heading into the battle to mess up your team, like a nanoboosted target.

**Additionally:**
Always slap your orb on someone who you need dead asap, like an ulting pharah

**In short:**
Put it one the person who is the biggest issue to you or your team at that moment in time